# Unique click tracking on Input fields/buttons on GTM

Tags: google-tag-manager, buttonclick

I am trying to get a track of unique clicks on Input fields/buttons via Google Tag Manager(GTM. 
Is it possible to track the unique clicks of a button?

By Unique clicks I meant, those are the number of unique visitors that clicked on a button/input element; for example, if the same visitor clicked 3 times on the same button, it will be reported as 3 clicks and 1 unique click.

Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it's definitely possible to track clicks on a specific element in GTM.

You can either track clicks on elements or clicks on links using the GTM click and link click triggers, and filter to clicks on specific elements using element IDs or CSS selectors.

Have a look at [this article](https://www.analyticsmania.com/post/google-tag-manager-click-tracking/) by Julius Fedorovicius, which goes into much more detail than I could in a stack overflow answer.

Comment: Thanks for your reply! But,
By Unique clicks I meant, those are the number of unique visitors that clicked on a button/input element; for example, if the same visitor clicked 3 times on the same button, it will be reported as 3 clicks and 1 unique click.

Comment: Which platform are you tracking this in? If it's Google Analytics then events and unique events are already tracked, so there is no need to do anything else, if you want to use a different platform then please say what it is!